# error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1 and ERROR: Failed building wheel for mysqlclient

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, docker, mysql-python

There are so many error .

```
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lssl
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcrypto
  collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
  error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for mysqlclient


  code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 
  '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-0p2809_2/install-record.txt --single- 
  version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
```

I tried python-dev also python3-dev .And changed mysqlclient version but nothing happend same issue.these codes are in docker file. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the two first lines, you're missing the `libssl-dev` system package; try `apt-get install -y libssl-dev` in your dockerfile.

You'll also need `libmysqlclient-dev`, if you haven't added that already.